# I have data streaming into a PCIe port, how best to save it directly to a remote drive connected through a 10GbE port?

Tags: remote-server, ethernet

Data will be arriving at a moderate rate of 30MBps from an external device through a PCIe. I want to move the data immediately off of my acquisition machine and store it on a remote drive on a server. My acquisition machine is connected to my server on a 10GbE line.

What happens in between when my data arrive on my PCIe and when it leaves on my ethernet card?  Any tips on how to design my system? Any special hardware needed?

First time poster, long-time listener

----edit----

input is arriving through kintex 7 eval board (https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/kcu105.html)

using the xillybus drivers (http://xillybus.com/) to communicate with an FPGA

output is moving to a TRENDnet 10 Gigabit PCIe Network Adapter

I have design choices about whether it will be a Windows or Linux machine.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Your question is too general. Please add some more details.